# iOS: Unit Testing UIViewController Components with XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I am implementing a unit test on the functionality of iOS UIButton in a view controller in Swift. The expected functionality of this button is as followed:

1. The button initially has a title of "Start"
2. After the button is pressed, the title changes to "Pause"

In short, I would like to test that the button's title is changed from "Start" to "Pause" after the button has been clicked.

Because the system needs a bit of time before the change takes place and is rendered on screen, I need to poll for a short amount of time to check the current title of the button until either the button title changes or the allotted time runs out.

Normally, I use Quick/Nimble framework for the unit testing and I use `expect(...).toEventually(...)` function to test this kind of polling. However, my team insists that I use XCTest framework for the sake of consistency, so I have to find some elegant way to implement the test with XCTest.

Do you have any suggestions for the implementation with XCTest framework?

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I can come up with is using `NSTimer` which triggers a condition check every small interval until the designated time runs out, and use `XCTestExpectation` and `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` in order to wait for the completion. (See more about XCTestExpectation [here](http://nshipster.com/xctestcase/))

Are there any better ways to implement this unit test?